# Cómo validar el click de un botón desde javascript en php

Tags: php, ajax

Estoy insertando datos en php con ajax, pero no en cuentro la manera de insertarlos solo si se da click al botón especificado, ya que el problema es que todo está en el mismo archivo login.php entonces si mando una consulta para saber si existe un usuario pues también va a insertar datos y los inserta en blanco porque pues obviamente no se le ha mandado nada.

¿Cómo hago para insertar un dato solo si le doy click al botón asignado en javascript sin importar que todo esté en el mismo archivo login.php?

```js
var loginButton = document.querySelector("login-button");

loginButton.onclick = function() {
    
    parameters = {
        'user': loginPhone.value,
        'password': loginPassword.value
    };
    
    $.ajax({
        data: parameters,
        url: 'login.php',
        type: 'POST',
        
        success: function(mensaje) {
            
        }
    });
    
}


// EN PHP SE CREAN DATOS EN BLANCO, YA QUE PRIMERO VALIDO SI EXISTE LA CUENTA Y DESPUES INSERTO PERO NO, SIGUE CREANDO

$user = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$base->query("INSERT INTO $tabla (user,password) VALUES ('$user','$password')");
```

```html
<button class="login-button"></button>
```

Comment: Estas mencionando que tanto la funcion ajax como php se encuentran en un solo archivo ? podrias poner más detalles y especificar como esta conformado el formulario donde ingresas los datos

Comment: La pregunta es: ¿por qué ligas ese código al botón Login? Deberías tener un botón Insert o algo así para lanzar la inserción. Puedes perfectamente usar el mismo archivo PHP si fuera necesario, pero aquí parece que el problema es una confusión de conceptos. ¿Qué tiene que ver un Login con un Insert?